# An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred

Tags: combobox, nullreferenceexception

I have this combobox and when I choose an option, it shows me that I need to check for null value.

This is the code:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add("text1");
    comboBox1.Items.Add("text2");
    comboBox1.Items.Clear();
    if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()=="text1")
    {
        lbl_k.Visible = true;
        txt_k.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        lbl_k.Visible = false;
        txt_k.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I solved that problem, but i have another, when i click on an option in the combobox, the options are duplicating on every click.

Answer (score 0):

Answer For your comment.

That is because you adding Item in `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged`. which is get called every time you select one.

so add your items outside this method like when your form loads.
Ex. Here

`Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load`